# Regarding relationship of DB tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Suppose we have many to one relationship between table A and table B. Now there are two possibilities to define this relation in Laravel.

1. while creating migration I use the "References" Keyword. and the run the migration
2. The other way is I use hasMany and belongsTo in model class corresponding to those tables and do not mention References and all in migration tables.

Can some one help me in understanding what approach I should follow. Or we need to have both the approach in our codebase to create relationships. Can some one throw some light on it. I am kind of confused. I am new to Laravel and learning these intricacies. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you should use both 1 and 2 to make Eloquent relations work. If you're using raw queries, you can use only 1, but the real power of Laravel is in Eloquent model relations.

> Eloquent assumes the foreign key of the relationship based on the
>   model name

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You should use both the approach,

- using references onto the migration itself leads to data integrity at database table level
- To really explore the power of laravel one should use Eloquent and this can be achieved by establishing eloquent relationships among Models.

Reference :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

! Happy Coding!